# Google sitemap hasn't been indexed after a few months

Tags: google-search-console, wordpress, sitemap

A few months ago I created a WordPress blog, installed the SEO by Yoast plugin, and submitted a sitemap to Google's Webmaster Tools.

However, my sitemap hasn't been indexed.

I've sent an e-mail to the Google team but didn't receive a reply.

What else can I do?

Comment: @closetnoc This should be an answer.......... =]

Comment: @TimMalone You are right of course. I like to drop little turdlings (like a rabbit with an eating disorder) here as guides for new users and leave room for others to answer. However, it has been 8/15 hours now... posted comment as an answer.

Comment: @closetnoc I reckon posting an answer still allows others to answer - SE model encourages multiple answers and voting on answers to rise the best to the top :)

Comment: @TimMalone Yes. Of course you are right again, however, someone new might not answer if there are already answers... especially from an established user... just a thought. I sometimes look to see if there are good answers. If I find them, then I might comment or just let it be. Sometimes, I can add another point of view, add detail, or a correct answer if one does not exist.

Comment: @TimMalone For the record, you are outstanding! I appreciate it. Thanks for the vote. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc True. I guess if you come back and convert to an answer later then it achieves both aims - both encouraging a new user to answer, and ensuring 'an answer' is there (there's currently [1034 questions with no answers](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers), I might start going through that at some stage!)

Comment: @TimMalone I did that sometime back in 2015 but did not get through them all. Even used tags to narrow them down. Also, old questions can have lousy answers that often echo the thinking of the time but not accurate none-the-less. I should jump in on some of those since they are still found in search. However, the low vote-count could indicate to a search user not to pay attention or even see the answer. There should be some kind of refresh option for old questions that allows for new answers to succeed when technology has changed over time. Just a thought. It could just be gas.

Answer (score 2):

If your pages are being indexed properly, that is all you need. Google uses the sitemap primarily to audit if they can properly crawl your site and not as a source of URLs **TO** crawl your site.

Sitemaps are only necessary when a site is extremely large or has content behind a paywall or login. Otherwise, Google will largely ignore the sitemap. There is nothing for you to do.

You will see the pages indexed change up and down from time to time while Google audits your site. This is normal. As well, it is often as much as a couple of months behind.

Answer (score 1):

If the website is crawled and indexed properly then you dont need to worry about sitemap. It important only when you have large number of pages.

However to expedite the process you go to webmaster > Crawl > Fetch as Google  - enter the url of your sitemap, usually it is sitemap.xml. Hit the fetch button to see if everything is ok and click on submit to index button.